# Writing Generic HttpClient Wrapper Functions

Tags: angular, typescript

Scenario:

I've got a bunch of services where I have tons and tons of duplicated code for data-calls, I want to reduce the amount of code necessary to create these by instead calling on a wrapper-function:

Basically, all of these functions do the same thing.

1. They take a return parameter,
2. They use either a post/get/delete method.
3. They return a promise.

This my attempt at generalizing a wrapper-function (for get):

```
public httpGetPromise<T extends any>(endpoint: string, returnType: T): Promise<T> {
    const promise: Promise<returnType> = new Promise<returnType>((resolve,reject) => {
        this.http.get<returnType>(`${this.endpointBaseUri}+${endpoint})
        .toPromise().then((response) => {
             resolve(response);
        }, (err) => {
             reject(response);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

This simplifies it somewhat. But I believe there must be better approaches out there.

Is there a better way of writing this wrapper-function to make it more generic and acceptable of different input-types?

Sample code for a `Get / Post / Delete` function (What my calls look without a wrapper):

```
public saveMachine(newMachine: Machine): Promise<Machine> {
    const promise: Promise<Machine> = new Promise<Machine>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post<Machine>(`${this.endpointBaseUri}/machines`, newMachine).toPromise().then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

    return promise;
}

public deleteMachine(machine: Machine): Promise<Machine> {
    const promise: Promise<Machine> = new Promise<Machine>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.delete<Machine>(this.endpointBaseUri + `/machines/${machine.id}`)
            .toPromise().then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });

    return promise;
}

public getMachinesConfigs(machineId: string): Promise<MachineConfig[]> {
    const promise: Promise<MachineConfig[]> = new Promise<MachineConfig[]>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<MachineConfig[]>(`${this.endpointBaseUri}/machines/${machineId}/machineconfigs`
        ).toPromise().then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

As you can see... There is a lot of possibility to generalize this into wrapper-functions.

This is what the calls would then look like with my suggest wrapper-function (for get):

```
public getMachinesConfig(machineId:string, MachineConfig[]): MachineConfig[] {
     const endpoint: string = `/machines/${machineId}/machineconfigs`;
     return this.wrapperService.httpGetPromise(endpoint, MachineConfig[]);
}
```

I'm using TypeScript `3.2.4`.

Sidenote: Is it possible in the wrapper-parameters to somehow pass along what  http-method type i want to use??

Like:

```
public promiseFunc(httpMethod:HttpClient,..., data?:any, etc...)
```

This way, A single function would handle all post get and delete promises.

Comment: why do you wrap the calls in a promise instead of simply calling `toPromise`? Makes no sense

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Can you please elaborate? Not sure how this would be a bad thing?

Comment: `new Promise((...) => this.http.toPromise().then(...).catch(...))` could be shortened to `this.http.toPromise()`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo How can I then utilize the resolve and reject responses?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo A more pressing issue is the fact that TS doesn't understand what I mean by `Promise<returnType>`.

Comment: thats because you are using generic types in a completely wrong way

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Lets say I want to do something with the response before i resolve it? How would i be able to do that with your suggestion?

Comment: If you have any suggestions to how I could improve my current approach, an answer would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just use a generic type parameter:

```
public httpGetPromise<T>(endpoint: string){
    const promise: Promise<T> = new Promise<T>((resolve,reject) => {
        this.http.get<T>(`${this.endpointBaseUri}${endpoint}`)
        .toPromise().then((response) => {
             resolve(response);
        }, (err) => {
             reject(reject);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

this.httpGetPromise<MachineConfig[]>(...)
```

Also I don't think the promise constructor is necessary here, you can just return the `Promise` retunred by `toPromise` :

```
public httpGetPromise<T>(endpoint: string){
    return this.http.get<T>(`${this.endpointBaseUri}${endpoint}`)
        .toPromise();
}
```

Your sample usage would look like:

```
public getMachinesConfig(machineId:string): MachineConfig[] {
     const endpoint: string = `/machines/${machineId}/machineconfigs`;
     return this.wrapperService.httpGetPromise<MachineConfig[]>(endpoint);
}
```